# Sum over numeric columns and report indices of column sums that lie within a specified range

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to accomplish the following task in R.

(1) sum over the columns that are numeric

(2) given two numbers, tell me the column numbers and/or names of the columns whose column sums are within that range, inclusive

**Example**:
I would like to sum the columns of the following data frame but there is unfortunately a column of characters causing apply to fail. Afterward, I would like to retrieve the column index of the columns that had sums between 655 and 855.

```
dat=data.frame(matrix(1:100, nrow=10), matrix(LETTERS[1:10], nrow=10))
apply(dat, 2, sum)
sum(dat[,7])
sum(dat[,9])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find out the columns that are numeric and use `colSums` to get their sum.

```
cols <- sapply(dat, is.numeric)
column_sum <- colSums(dat[cols])
column_sum

# X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8  X9 X10 
# 55 155 255 355 455 555 655 755 855 955
```

To find out values that are in range you can do :

```
column_sum[column_sum >= 655 & column_sum <= 855]
# X7  X8  X9 
#655 755 855 

#to get only the names
names(column_sum[column_sum >= 655 & column_sum <= 855])
#[1] "X7" "X8" "X9"
```

---

Using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum)) %>%
  select(where(~between(., 655, 855)))
```